# Conditional Page Display when application opens for the first time

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

Hi I am just starting to learn angular && angular-ui-router and am trying to figure out how to determine when the app is opened for the first time to send the user to the login page or home page.

This is what i have so far:

```
codeArtApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url : '/login',
        templateUrl:'App/scripts/login/loginView.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
    .state('profile', {
        url : '/profile',
        templateUrl:'App/scripts/login/loginView.html',
        controller: 'profileCtrl'
    })
    .state('404', {
        url: '/404',
        templateUrl:'App/scripts/views/404.html'
    });


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("404");
```

});

```
codeArtApp.run(['$state', '$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope, $log){
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState){
    if(fromState.url === '^' && toState.url !== 'login'){
        $state.go('login');
    }

});
```

}]);

What I assumed here is that if `fromState.url` is set to `^` then the application is starting for the first time.

For some reason this code enters an infinite loop and I gt this stacktrace:
[image]

Now from what I can tell this happened because event if `$state.go('login')` gets execute `toState.url` is always **404**.

I had hoped if  `$state.go('login')` gets executed `toState.url` would have been set to login and that call would not be executed anymore.

I may not be setting this logic in the right place...

Can anyone tell me how conditionaly page displayed is achieved in Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a link to working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aYmykLnWZVUwg4trMmVX?p=preview), the main changes are shown in the code:

```
codeArtApp.run(['$state', '$rootScope',
 function($state, $rootScope, $log) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {

      // instead of 
      // toState.url !== 'login'
      // we compare 
      // toState.name !== 'login'
      var shouldLogin = fromState.url === '^' 
              && toState.name !== 'login';

      if(shouldLogin)
      {
        // this way we stop current execution
        event.preventDefault();
        // and navigate to login
        $state.go('login');  
      }
    });
 }
]);
```

The `toState.url` would contain the url, i.e. `'/login'` instead of `'login'`. Also check the : [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) to see more about the `event.preventDefault();` . The [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aYmykLnWZVUwg4trMmVX?p=preview) showing the above...

Comment: How do i check local storage value before checking condition here?

Comment: Add `LocalStorage` provider as a dependency and ask for that value... *(run phase has access to all initiated providers...)*

Comment: Simply i am doing like this ::::
App.run(['$state', '$rootScope','$localstorage',
 function($state, $rootScope, $log,$localstorage,$scope) {
            $scope.CLoginData = $localstorage.get('SignInUser'); 
            alert($scope.CLoginData);
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) { 
            
            });
        }
]);

Comment: but every time i am getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$localstorage.get')

Comment: Well, that should be brand new answer! comments are not good place to solve your errors.. but obviously you have mismatch of the parameter names and function arguments .. I guess that storage would be with S

Comment: I posted as a question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356020/conditional-navigate-when-app-opens-for-the-first-time-in-angular/35356612?noredirect=1#comment58420184_35356612.

Answer (score 7):

In your `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` call you can pass a function instead of a string. Something like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector){

    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
    var Storage = $injector.get('Storage');

    if (Storage.has('authToken')) {
        $state.go('home');
    }
    else {
        $state.go('login');    
    }

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how do i get "var Storage = $injector.get('Storage');"  inside here. I am getting error for this