# Conditional Navigate when app opens for the first time in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing mobile hybrid app with the help of Angular and Ionic.

I have conditional login based on user role. On the login time i am getting role and based on role i am navigating to the role based page.
For this i am saving my role data in LocalStorage and after login i am checking the same.

But i am not able to handle  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/user');`  conditionally.

Because if i am login as a user2 so i closed my app. Again if i am opening my app the page should be different but it is navigating on `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` page.

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349977/conditional-page-display-when-application-opens-for-the-first-time) but not able to solve my problem.

Comment: any possibility to get localStorage data in .config or .run method?

Comment: Are you using ui-router?

Comment: *If you'd have a working (broken) plunker, it would make it easier to fix it and help you...*

Answer (score 0):

As u said you are using `ui-router`, you can use `$state.go`.

Ui-router provides `transitionStart` event. Here you can use your logic to go to whichever route you want to redirect. You will have to use your local storage value in this event.

Comment: that is what i am not getting localStorage access inside this

Comment: What do you mean by not able to access local storage. Are you getting some error?

Comment: YES : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$localstorage.get')

Comment: I did like this >>>>>>App.run(['$state', '$rootScope','$localstorage',
 function($state, $rootScope, $log,$localstorage,$scope) {
            $scope.LoginData = $localstorage.get('SignInUser'); 
            alert($scope.LoginData);
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) { 
            
            });
        }
]);

Comment: Then check if you are properly setting the signinuser value.

Comment: I have that value in local storage based on that value i am doing another things.